# Building a TreeView is causing my form to freeze

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to build an app that pulls back all the directories and files and builds a Treeview. I have some code below that does this, however it seams to cause my UI to freeze as it is building.

I'm unsure if this a threading issue? I think that the code that builds the tree view is on a separate thread to the UI although this is one bit i'm unsure of.

I've also read that i may need to look into UI Virtualisation / data Virtualisation. If anyone could point me into the correct direction that would be very helpful.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            btnSearch.Text = "Searching...";
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            Application.DoEvents();    
            Thread treeThread = new Thread(() => ListDirectory(lstTreeView, "C:\\"));
            treeThread.Start();
            btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => treeView.Nodes.Clear()));
            var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => treeView.Nodes.Add(CreatedirNode(rootDirectoryInfo))));
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lblCount.Items.Add("Time taken in Sec " + (elapsedMs)/1000)));

        }
```

I think this maybe the reason as I think the UI is freezing as `directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));` looks to be writing on the UI thread?

```
private static TreeNode CreatedirNode(DirectoryInfo DirI) {

            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(DirI.Name);
            try
            {
                foreach (var directory in DirI.GetDirectories())
                    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreatedirNode(directory));

                foreach (var file in DirI.GetFiles())
                    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));

            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }

            return directoryNode;
        }
```

Comment: the problem is, you start a thread, then your thread then delegates back to the UI thread

Comment: @KeithNicholas can you point me to where the treeThread delegates back to the UI thread? is it CreatedirNode?

Comment: Your `this.Invoke` calls are where you're delegating back to the UI thread. Try calling `lstTreeView.BeginUpdate();` prior to `Thread treethread` and then call `lstTreeView.EndUpdate();` once your thread has completed. `BackgroundWorker` might be a better fit than using a `Thread`.

Comment: Try it with `[Build the TreeView Nodes, then... ]  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { [TreeView].SuspendLayout(); [TreeView].BeginUpdate();  [TreeView].Items.AddRange([Your nodes' pre-built collection]); [TreeView].EndUpdate(); [TreeView].ResumeLayout(true)}));`. You could (should) use a Task instead of a Thread.

Comment: Most likely you don't need a separate thread. All you need is to build the  node structure non-visually and then add the root node(s) to the treeview.

Comment: @TaW how would i build the nodes structure non-visually? i quite new to C# and windows forms in general

Comment: You do that pretty much exactly the same. Just don't add anything to the TreeView; instead create a node yourself: `TreeNode myRoot = new TreeNode();` - Then add all the nodes to this root and when it is complete add it to the TreeView. This way the diaply is updated only __once__ instead of n-times for n nodes.. TreeView layout is often expensive..